# uninitialized constant RsvpsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so i'm getting this error when I press my rsvp button from my ui. Maybe theres something wrong with my route or something wrong with my controller.
I'm not too sure at this point. I'm quite new to rails and I've been stuck on this issue for far too long. When I do make some changes another error pops up.  I would truly appreciate some help

```
class RsvpController < ApplicationController

 def create
    rsvp = current_user.rsvp.build({post_id: params[:id]})
    if rsvp.save 
    end
 end

end
```

post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
   unless current_user == @post.user
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, notice: 'User is not owner'
   end
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end



  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:date, :user_id, :description, :name, :address)
    end
    load_and_authorize_resource
def create
  @rsvp=rsvp.new
end

end
```

=

routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  resources :posts
  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
  get 'home/ruby_meetup'

  resources :posts do
  post 'rsvp', to: 'rsvps#create', on: :member
end
```

Also I want the number of users who rsvped/registered to show up but I'm getting random numbers and letters showing up on my ui. Is there something not right with my show page?

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<p>
  <strong>Date:</strong>
  <%= @post.date %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Name:</strong>
    <%= @post.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>User_id:</strong>
  <%= @post.user_id %>
</p>
<p><strong>Address:</strong> <%= @post.address %></p>
<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @post.description %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>registered:</strong>
    <%=@post.user %>
</p>


<% if current_user == @post.user %>
 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%end%>
 <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

<div class="rsvp"><%= button_to "Rsvp now", rsvp_post_path(@post), class: "btn btn-primary" %></div>






<div class="map"><%= image_tag "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=#{@post.latitude},#{@post.longitude}&markers=#{@post.latitude},#{@post.longitude}&zoom=12&size=450x400&key=AIzaSyCKzKMEhSNgwSXf7WV71pHWgzdpMkPn8W4",
class: 'img-fluid img-rounded', alt: "#{@post} on the map"%>
</div>
```

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

controller class name should be RsvpsController currently its RsvpController, note that `s` is missing after `Rsvp`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your route to this:

```
post 'rsvp', to: 'rsvp#create', on: :member
```

Comment: nope your code is this " post 'rsvp', to: 'rsvps#create', on: :member" find what's new in my code , you have committed a sliiy mistake :)